# ListView inside GridLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, grid-layout

I have a `ListView` inside a `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`, here is my code:

```
        <!-- Sort -->
        <Space
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_content_space"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            app:layout_rowSpan="2" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/none"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_content_row_height"
            android:text="@string/sort"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_sort"
            style="@style/Spinner"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/none"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_content_row_height"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_content_space"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            app:layout_rowSpan="2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_filter"
            style="@style/TextView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/none"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_content_row_height"
            android:text="@string/filter"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_filter"
            style="@style/Spinner"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/none"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_content_row_height"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/divider_margin"
            app:layout_columnSpan="4" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/layout_courses"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/none"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/none"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:scrollbars="none"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="@dimen/none"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_columnSpan="4"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>`
```

and https://goo.gl/bJub9t this is how it looks in the `Design` tab in AndroidStudio

What it's shown in the picture it's exactly what I wanted to achieve, but when I run my app in an Android device the `ListView` it's completely empty.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that the `ListView` width and height are both 0dp (that's the value for `@dimen/none`), but with these values it's the only way I can get my desired result.

Comment: Well the widget of your ListView shouldn't be 0dp, since this isn't needed.

Comment: Just looking at the screenshot here, xml looks good. Is your list getting populated with the data you want? If you run the app without any code that populates the list/grid then it won't show on the app (even if it shows on the preview)

Comment: The listview on the Designer shows dummy elements which are not going to be displayed when you open your application on the emulator or a test device. You first need to populate the listview in your activity or fragment in order to see elements there.

Comment: @LucasCrawford when I remove those two attributes my `ListView` show its content but it will not scroll

Comment: Got it, I know the solution now. Give me a sec I will add an answer

Comment: @derpycat I ran my app with breakpoints in my code when the `ListView` it's been populated and everything it's been added properly, it's just not showing up.

Comment: So the GridLayout you want to pass the scroll on to ListView right??

Comment: @LucasCrawford yes, I want to scroll only in my `ListView` and that the `ListView`'s height fills the rest of the space available

Comment: Why not just place the ListView below the GridLayout, does your layout really need to be constructed with the ListView being apart of the GridLayout?

Comment: @LucasCrawford that's the power of a second opinion! Your suggestion works perfectly. Guess I was in a stuck state of mind. If you want you can add your comment as an answer to mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just place the ListView below the GridLayout? The layout doesn't really need to be constructed with the ListView being apart of the GridLayout since you are just trying to create a fixed header above the ListView for sorting and filtering :)